# Jquery sort div based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sorting

I have this short bit of code to sort / ascend div by number. But I want to add other conditions to sort by. Right now, it's only sorting it just based on **points** class. But I want it to also apply conditions on **times** and combine with points.

Generally these divs sort ascend from large number to low number. If the number is equal, it will show those whose time is less. If the number is equal, it will search to see which **times** is the lowest. And it will show it First.

```js
$(function(){ 
    var sortedList = $('.contest_entry').toArray().sort(function(lhs, rhs){ 
      return parseInt($(rhs).children("span.points").text(),10) - parseInt($(lhs).children("span.points").text(),10); 
   });
    $("#list").html(sortedList);
});
```

```css
.contest_entry
{
  padding:10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin:10px 0px;
}

.points
{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
<div class="contest_entry">
<span class="points">14</span>
<span class="times"> 12:39 </span>
</div> 
<div class="contest_entry">
<span class="points">16</span>
<span class="times"> 09:55 </span>
</div>
<div class="contest_entry">
<span class="points">19</span>
<span class="times"> 17:19 </span>
</div>
<div class="contest_entry">
<span class="points">19</span>
<span class="times"> 17:34 </span>
</div>
<div class="contest_entry">
<span class="points">19</span>
<span class="times"> 17:20 </span>
</div>
</div>
```

In summary, I want to add multiple conditions to filter or sort the divs.

Comment: You can perform whatever comparison logic you want within your sort function. What's your question?

Comment: I updated your javascript function, if that helped you, please mark question as solved

Comment: @freedomn-m 
 In my edit: i formated tho code 
And in my answer i posted the updated javascript function 
,Sorry but i didn't understantd what are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code please

```
$(function(){ 
    var sortedList = $('.contest_entry').toArray().sort(function(lhs, rhs){ 
        var lhsPoints = parseInt($(lhs).find(".child span.points").text(),10);
        var rhsPoints = parseInt($(rhs).find(".child span.points").text(),10);
        if (lhsPoints === rhsPoints) {
            // Compare the "times" class if the "points" class is equal
            return $(lhs).find(".child span.times").text() > $(rhs).find(".child span.times").text() ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return rhsPoints - lhsPoints;
        }
    });
    $("#list").html(sortedList);
});
```